# Can I log user events or actions in CloudFront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

Can I log user events or actions in CloudFront in AWS?
I need the same functionality like in Google Analytics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable Cloudfront logs to S3 and use Athena to query [Link to guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/AccessLogs.html)

[How to create table in Athena from Cloudfront logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/cloudfront-logs.html)

You can track number of user accessing specific path or query, but it can only track requests, not some "click in page and do some action without requests" event . It's also can't track specific users or send further information, which you are able to send to Google Analytic using JS.

Edit: You can also use CF metrics to track requests. Have a look at this: https://dev.to/rimutaka/replacing-google-analytics-with-cloudfront-metrics-15o0

It also cost a bit for S3 and Athena if you are doing it too much.